# Аргументы функции имеют тип - имя класса, как реализовать? c++, VS13

Tags: c++, visual-studio, классы, функции

В комментариях - то что уже готово

Создать класс вещественных чисел Double.

//Определить перегруженную функцию, возвращающую максимальное из двух 
аргументов.

//Функция не является членом класса Double.

Перегруженные функции имеют аргументы типа int, double, Double.

//Тело перегруженных функций должны быть одинаковыми.

Вот тут вопрос как сделать тип Double?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class Double{

};

int func(int num1, int num2){
    int value;
    if (num1 > num2) value = num1;
    if (num1 < num2) value = num2;
    return value;
}

double func(double num1, double num2){
    double value;
    if (num1 > num2) value = num1;
    if (num1 < num2) value = num2;
    return value;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Кстати, как сделать проверку вводимое число double или int?

Comment: вам максимум нужен? тогда предлагаю сразу писать `max(num1,num2)`, если нужно самому то `T func(const T num1, const T num2)
{
 if (num1 < num2) return num1;
 return num2;
} ` Для вашего класса `Double` есть возможность писать `pair<double,double>` и так далее.

Comment: Как-как, определите `operator<` для вашего типа `Double` для начала. Узнайте, как такое делать правильно.

Comment: Первое и главное у вас не готово: **Создать класс вещественных чисел Double**. Как только вы его создадите, так сразу станет понятно, что дальше. На всякий случай - создать класс не значит просто набрать `class Double`...

Comment: @Harry там же написано что в комментах то что готово, и вот я не знаю как он должен выглядеть под это задание и как его использовать

Comment: Набросал начало. Дальше справитесь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала создайте класс. Примерно так.

```
class Double
{
public:
    Double(double val = 0.0):val(val){}
    Double(const Double&)             = default;
    ~Double()                         = default;
    Double& operator= (const Double&) = default;

    operator double() const { return val; }
private:
    double val;
};

bool operator < (const Double& x, const Double& y)
{
    return static_cast<double>(x) < static_cast<double>(y);
}
```

Дальше все понятно? :)

Comment: Сейчас попробую, мне не совсем понятно как оператор работает, что он возвращает? true or false?
Прост я с++ вообще не учил и потому даже элементарные вещи не понятны, заранее извиняюсь за глупые вопросы

Comment: Он возвращает `true`, если `x < y`, и `false` в противном случае.